# New behavior in data.table? .N / something with `by` (calculate proportion)

Tags: r, data.table

I updated to the latest version of `data.table` - 1.9.4, from a medium-recent prior version (I think 1.8.X), and now I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

```
set.seed(12312014)

# a vector of letters a:e, each repeated between 1 and 10 times
type <- unlist(mapply(rep, letters[1:5], round(runif(5, 1, 10), 0)))

# a random vector of 3 categories
category <- sample(c('small', 'med', 'large'), length(type), replace=T)
my_dt <- data.table(type, category)
```

Say I want the proportion of category by type. I used to do that by doing this:

```
my_dt[, type_n:=.N, by=type]
my_dt[, .N/type_n, by=.(type, category)][order(type, category)]
```

what I get with data.table 1.9.4:

```
# type category        V1
# 1:    a    large 0.2500000
# 2:    a    large 0.2500000
# 3:    a      med 0.2500000
# 4:    a      med 0.2500000
# 5:    a    small 0.5000000
# 6:    a    small 0.5000000
# 7:    a    small 0.5000000
# 8:    a    small 0.5000000
# 9:    b    large 0.4285714
# 10:    b    large 0.4285714
# 11:    b    large 0.4285714
# 12:    b      med 0.4285714
# (...and so on, 42 rows long)
```

but what I used to get, I'm virtually certain, was this (simple proportion of cat by type):

```
# type category        V1
# 1:    a    large 0.2500000
# 2:    a      med 0.2500000
# 3:    a    small 0.5000000
# 4:    b    large 0.4285714
# 5:    b      med 0.4285714
# 6:    b    small 0.1428571
# 7:    c    large 0.3000000
# 8:    c      med 0.1000000
# 9:    c    small 0.6000000
# 10:    d    large 0.2222222
# 11:    d      med 0.6666667
# 12:    d    small 0.1111111
# 13:    e    large 0.3750000
# 14:    e      med 0.3750000
# 15:    e    small 0.2500000
```

I can get the desired result with this:

```
unique(my_dt[, .N/type_n, by=.(type, category)][order(type, category)])
```

...but I wondered if there's a preferred way in the new data.table syntax. I know I can also just use `prop.table`, but I want it long format.

```
prop.table(table(my_dt), margin=1)
# category
# type     large       med     small
#    a 0.2500000 0.2500000 0.5000000
#    b 0.4285714 0.4285714 0.1428571
#    c 0.3000000 0.1000000 0.6000000
#    d 0.2222222 0.6666667 0.1111111
#    e 0.3750000 0.3750000 0.2500000
```

For reference, my sessionInfo call gives:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0    data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] chron_2.3-45     colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2    
 [7] MASS_7.3-33      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4    
[13] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: So which one of those results do you actually want?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you are happy with `prop.table` and just want a long format, you could also do `data.table(prop.table(table(my_dt), margin=1))`.

Comment: Or `my_dt[, prop.table(table(category)), by=type]`

Comment: What I called the 'desired result', and showed above, is what I get with `unique(my_dt[, .N/type_n, by=.(type, category)][order(type, category)])`. I used to get this without wrapping with `unique()`.

Comment: I don't see how you would have been able to get this without `unique` since you are using `:=`. There must be come confusion in the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @Ananda, you are right, and that seems preferable to the `unique()` call. I was just caught by surprise at the change in output, I will see if I can replicate on older machine with old data.table to be 100% sure

Comment: I think you're misremembering. Maybe you used to do `my_dt[, .N/type_n[1], by=.(type, category)][order(type, category)]` instead.

Comment: I didn't have the older data.table version on the other machine and I'm not gonna roll back just to check, but now here are several methods that all work. (I like that formulation eddi, thanks) So, thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try

```
my_dt[, .N, by=.(type,category)][, prop:=N/sum(N), by=type][]

    type category N      prop
 1:    a    small 4 0.5000000
 2:    a      med 2 0.2500000
 3:    a    large 2 0.2500000
 4:    b      med 3 0.4285714
 5:    b    large 3 0.4285714
 6:    b    small 1 0.1428571
 7:    c    large 3 0.3000000
 8:    c    small 6 0.6000000
 9:    c      med 1 0.1000000
10:    d      med 6 0.6666667
11:    d    large 2 0.2222222
12:    d    small 1 0.1111111
13:    e    small 2 0.2500000
14:    e      med 3 0.3750000
15:    e    large 3 0.3750000
```